# rails scope with where = false, work differently on heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have this on my code:

```
scope :to_send, where(:sent => false)
```

on local with mysql I see this:

```
`scheduled_messages`.`sent` = 0
```

On Heroku instead (with pg):

```
"scheduled_messages"."sent" = 'f'
```

Why?

Comment: Humm aparently it work the same way... maybe I'm wrong and this is a normal behaviour on PG?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PostgreSQL has a native [`boolean`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-boolean.html) type where true is represented by the string literal `'t'` and false by `'f'` (there are other literals but those are the most common ones). MySQL doesn't have a native boolean type and uses C-style integers for booleans instead.

The MySQL and PostgreSQL adapters for Rails take care of translating native Ruby values (such as `false`) to their equivalents for the database in question (`0` for MySQL, `'f'` for PostgreSQL).

Looks like you're developing on top of MySQL but deploying on PostgreSQL. The differences in boolean handling is the least of your worries. You really should be developing and deploying on top of the same database.